# How to run a for loop in angularJS without using html tags?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I am developing an application in angularJS where the structure of it is in a way that I have to run a for each loop and I cannot use any html element or `div` to do `ng-repeat` to loop over.

In django we do something like:

```
{% for item in list %}

{{ item }}

{% endfor %}
```

Is there something i can do like in this angularJS so i can loop over items without using any `<>` tags? Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: No, it has to be within javascript or html, angular parses your html to do the loops. Only alternative is using a template engine.

Comment: Why can't you use html elements?

Comment: Where do you want to loop? In javascript file or html file?

Comment: @AndrewDonovan how do I do it in javascript?

Comment: We will need more details. Are you asking how to do it in general ?
Are you in a directive, or simply in a view ?

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you use divs?

```
<div ng-repeat-start="item in list">

</div>
<!-- more content -->
</div ng-repeat-end>

</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points

Comment: poster's question was how to do this without introducing extra HTML tags